# Not sure why I keep getting this error: TypeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object is not callable

Tags: python, typeerror

I've seen a bunch of similar questions to this with great answers but I'm not sure how to apply them to the following code. I am just learning and other than this error I think I am good to go on this assignment so any help would be much appreciated!

```
def do_research():

    num_month = 1
    num_cages = int(input("Number of cages: "))
    num_adults = int(input("Adult pairs in the first month: "))
    num_babies = int(input("Pairs of babies in the first month: "))
    total = num_adults + num_babies
    output_file = open("rabbits.csv", "w")
    output_file.writelines("# Table of rabbit pairs\n")
    output_file.writelines("Month, Adults, Babies, Total\n")
    output_file.writelines(str(num_month) + ",  ")
    output_file.writelines(str(num_adults) + ",  ")
    output_file.writelines(str(num_babies) + ",  ")
    output_file.writelines(str(total) + "\n")
    while (total / 2) < num_cages:
        num_month += 1
        num_babies = num_adults
        num_adults += num_babies
        total = num_adults + num_babies
        output_file.writelines(str(num_month) + ",  ")
        output_file.writelines(str(num_adults) + ",  ")
        output_file.writelines(str(num_babies) + ",  ")
        output_file.writelines(str(total) + "\n")
    output_file.writelines("# Cages will run out in month " + str(num_month))
    output_file()
do_research()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the second to last line of your code:

```
output_file()
```

That line doesn't make sense.  Just as the error message says, the object being referenced by `output_file` is not callable.  It'a file handle...a reference to an open file.  That isn't something that is callable.  Said another way, you can't treat that object like it is a function or method.  I assume that this is just a syntax error and you meant something else.

In the future, please supply the stack trace that accompanies the error message you are getting.  I assume that in this case, the accompanying stack trace is pointing to this line of your code.